# Issues with the usage of @PreUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have the following class:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MappedModel
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long mId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "rec_created_dtm", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date recordCreatedDTM;

    @Column(name = "rec_cre_user_id", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private Long recordCreatedUserId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_update_dtm", nullable = false)
    private Date lastUpdateDTM;

    @Column(name = "last_update_user_id", nullable = true)
    private Long lastUpdateUserId;

//  @PrePersist
//  protected void onCreate()
//  {
//      this.lastUpdateDTM = this.recordCreatedDTM = new Date();
//  }
//
//  @PreUpdate
//  protected void onUpdate()
//  {
//      lastUpdateDTM = new Date();
//  }

  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  protected void updateDates() {
    if (this.recordCreatedDTM == null) {
        this.recordCreatedDTM = new Date();
    }
    lastUpdateDTM = new Date();
  }
```

This class is used by all my entity classes.

So I have the following class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer extends MappedModel implements Serializable
{

    /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2543425088717298236L;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id",nullable=true,updatable=true,insertable=true)
    private Address mAddress;
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address  extends MappedModel implements Serializable
{

    /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3505413538055124608L;

  @Column(name="address_line_1", length=150, nullable=false)
  private String mAddressLine;

  @Column(name="city", length=150, nullable=false)
  private String mCity;

  @Column(name="state", length=2, nullable=true)
  private String mState;

  @Column(name="postal_code", length=10, nullable=false)
  private String mPostalCode;
```

So, when I create a new customer I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value: vsg.ecotrak.dataaccess.domain.Address.lastUpdateDTM; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: vsg.ecotrak.dataaccess.domain.Address.lastUpdateDTM

org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you please provide the full stacktrace of your exception. I don't think you have an issue with `PreUpdate` or `PrePersist`. The message `not-null property references a null or transient value: vsg.ecotrak.dataaccess.domain.Address.lastUpdateDTM` says that `lastUpdateDTM` is `null` and that probably Hibernate fails before triggering any `@Pre...` methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate` callbacks do work in a `MappedSuperclass`... at least when using the `EntityManager` API from JPA, which is not clear in your case.

Are you using the `EntityManager` or the `Session` API? In the later case, methods annotated using the `PrePersist`, `PreUpdate` annotations from JPA won't get called (and my suggestion would be to use [a listener or an interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)).

Comment: Using Session - not using JPA

Comment: well that makes sense then - guess I missed that in the documentation - thanks

Comment: Actually, we can live with JPA callbacks and Hibernate Session: http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com/2013/08/prepersist-and-preupdate-not-working.html