# Hibernate pre update not updating field

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi everyone I'm having some problems with the `updated_at` column in my database. I'm using hibernate and when I update a model, everything works fine except for the `@preUpdate` method. All my application models are extending this base model:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class BaseModel implements Serializable {

    // VARIABLES ---------------------------------------------------------------
private Integer globalKey;
private Integer id;
private Date createdAt;
private Date updatedAt;
private Date deletedAt;
private User createUser;
private User updateUser;
private User deleteUser;

    // CONSTRUCTORS ------------------------------------------------------------

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS -----------------------------------------------------

    // [hashCode, equals and toString methods] ---------------------------------

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        createdAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        updatedAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

And this is the method in the DAO for the update:

```
public MYOBJECT updateEntity(MYOBJECT entity, User updateUser) throws Exception {
    entity.setUpdateUser(updateUser);

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);

    return entity;
}
```

Am I missing something? In my database I see:

```
---------------------------------------------
| id    | updated_at    | id_user_update    |
| 1     | NULL          | 1                 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is "@PrePersist" working correctly? Neither "@PrePersist" or "@PreUpdate" should work using Session API. EntityManager should work just fine. Maybe you should refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121628/issues-with-the-usage-of-preupdate/)

Comment: `@PrePersist` works properly and when I add a new model the method `onCreate()` is called. I'm using spring and hibernate together so I don't know if the EntityManager is set and/or has a proper configuration, if you need I can edit my post including spring and hibernate configurations

Comment: If you are using SessionFactory then it's pretty likely that EntityManager is not used at all. My best bet here would be to try an implementation using EntityManager, but unfortunately i don't know how to setup this kind of stuff with Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem [here](http://notatube.blogspot.it/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html).

But just a little bit modified... Here is my code:

First of all I've removed from the `BaseModel` class these two methods:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
    updatedAt = new Date();
}
```

Then I've created a `BaseTimestamps` interface, used to set up my createdAt and updatedAt variables

```
public interface BaseTimestamps {

    /**
     * On create event.
     * used to setup a the creation variable.
     * 
     * @param createdAt
     */
    void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt);

    /**
     * On update event.
     * used to setup a the update variable.
     * 
     * @param updatedAt
     */
    void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt);
}
```

Finally I've created two listeners for the **hibernate session factory** in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

```
// SAVE LISTENER
public class SaveListener extends DefaultSaveEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof BaseTimestamps) {
            BaseTimestamps record = (BaseTimestamps) event.getObject();
            record.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        }

        super.onSaveOrUpdate(event);
    }

}

// UPDATE LISTENER
public class UpdateListener extends DefaultUpdateEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof BaseTimestamps) {
            BaseTimestamps record = (BaseTimestamps) event.getObject();
            record.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
        }

        super.onSaveOrUpdate(event);
    }

}
```

And here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="my.package.MyModel"/>
    // ............................
    <mapping class="my.package.OtherModel"/>  
      <event type="save">
         <listener class="my.package.SaveListener"/>
      </event>   
      <event type="update">
         <listener class="my.package.UpdateListener"/>
      </event>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I perform creation or updates, everything works fine and I see in my database the correct values.